# The constructor SamplePagerAdapter(List) refers to the missing type List

Tags: android, java

**fltut.java**

```
 public class fltut extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fltut, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.fld1));
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.img);
        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl1);
        TextView stpView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.stp);
        stpView.setText("1/12");
        pages.add(page);

             ...

        View page12 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fltut, null);
        TextView textView12 = (TextView) page12.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        textView12.setText(getResources().getString (R.string.fld12));
        ImageView imgView12 = (ImageView) page12.findViewById(R.id.img);
        imgView12.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl12);
        TextView stpView12 = (TextView) page12.findViewById(R.id.stp);
        stpView12.setText("12/12");
        pages.add(page12);

        SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(pages); //ошибка здесь: The constructor SamplePagerAdapter(List<View>) refers to the missing type List
        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        setContentView(viewPager);

}
```

**SamplePagerAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    List<View> pages = null;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(List<View> pages){
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

**При запуске fltut.java:**

> The constructor SamplePagerAdapter(List<View>) refers to the missing type List    attut.java

И приложение вылетает. Самое интересное - раньше работало без ошибки. Ничего не менял, но почему-то появилось ошибка.

Ну и вопрос - **как исправить?**

p.s. Сори за много кода, старался сократить как мог :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<View> pages = null;
```

на

```
List<View> pages;
```